# R : Calling a Function

Tags: r

I have a matrix :

```
x <- cbind(x1 = 3, x2 = c(4:1, 2:5))
dimnames(x)[[1]] <- letters[1:8]
```

How do the following codes work ?

```
cave <- function(x, c1, c2) c(mean(x[c1]), mean(x[c2]))
apply(x,1, cave,  c1="x1", c2=c("x1","x2"))
```

Particularly I am not understanding the argument , `c(mean(x[c1]), mean(x[c2]))`  inside the function  `cave`.

Also we call a function in this way  `cave(x,a,b)` . But inside the `apply` function where is the input when we call the `cave` function ?

Comment: This should be helpful https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/

Comment: Please note that looping through the rows and averaging a subset of the elements is less efficient than using built-in vectorized functions to perform such operations. For instance, it would be better in this case to run `rbind(rowMeans(x[,"x1",drop=F]), rowMeans(x[,c("x1", "x2")]))` or, even better, `rbind(x[,"x1"], rowMeans(x[,c("x1", "x2")]))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a function, the last thing listed is implicitly returned. Thus when you define `cave` as

```
cave <- function(x, c1, c2) {
    c(mean(x[c1]), mean(x[c2]))
}
```

this is the same as

```
cave <- function(x, c1, c2) {
    return(c(mean(x[c1]), mean(x[c2])))
}
```

In R, vectors are defined by concatenating elements using `c()`. Thus `c(a, b)` makes a vector of length 2 with elements `a` and `b`. In this case, `a` is the mean of the input `x` at the index given by `c1` and `b` is the mean of `x` at the index given by `c2`.

When you `apply()` this function to `x` over dimension 1, you're computing `cave()` on every row of `x`.

The syntax of `apply()` is as follows:

```
apply(x, # object input to the function
      1, # dimension of x over which to apply the function, 1=rows, 2=columns
      cave, # function to apply
      c1="x1", c2=c("x1", "x2") # any further arguments to the function
      )
```

Apply `cave()` to the first row gives us a vector consisting of the mean of `x1` (which is just `x1` since it's the mean of a single number) and the mean of `x1` and `x2`. The mean of 3 is 3 and the mean of 3 and 4 is 3.5, so the output is `c(3, 3.5)`.

We repeat that for every row in `x`, and in the end we get this:

```
       a b   c d   e f   g h
[1,] 3.0 3 3.0 3 3.0 3 3.0 3
[2,] 3.5 3 2.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4
```

You can see that column `a` corresponds to `cave()` on row `a` of `x` and so on.